# Wordpress Schema.org Markup. What value does it add?

Tags: templates, google-search, search-engines, html

I've been adding all the *"recommended"* **schema.org** markup to my sites for awhile now. Most of the schema markup [adds value to google searches](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/).

There's other markup though that I've been using and I'm not really sure who actually uses it (search engines, other sites, etc).

**Specifically, for this question, I'm wondering about the wordpress related schema.org markup:**

**Header:** `<header itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WPHeader">`

**Sidebar:** `<aside itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WPSideBar">`

**Footer:** `<footer itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WPFooter">`

Does anyone know what the purpose of this markup is? Does it add SEO value? If so how and where? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WP` in their URLs is not related to WordPress, it’s just a shorthand for ***W***eb**P**age. These types all have the type [`WebPageElement`](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) as parent.

In my opinion, using `WebPageElement` or one of its sub-types (like `WPHeader` etc.) is pointless for general web pages (there are some [special cases and non-HTML contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867175/1591669) where it might make sense to use these types). It can even be hindering to have these types, because it’s not (easily) possible to provide content in `WPHeader`/`WPFooter`/`WPSideBar` as value for a property that should belong to the parent `WebPage` item (e.g., if your `WPFooter` contains a license statement, the [`license`](http://schema.org/license) property would specify the license for the `WPFooter`, not for the `WebPage`).

Neither Google Search ([doc.](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/)) nor Bing ([doc.](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/marking-up-your-site-with-structured-data-3a93e731)) nor Yandex ([doc.](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/schema-org/what-is-schema-org.xml)) document any feature that would make use of these types.

Comment: Ha I'm an idiot, been thinking it was schema directly related to wordpress. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that WordPress core adds, it is something that themes add, and to know why, you will have to ask the authors.